# Plex: Thumbnails are loaded but videos do not play; spinner stays on screen indefinitely

Tags: video, plex

Whether it is a Movie, Home Movie or TV Show, the thumbnails appear successfully, which means a connection to the Plex server running on my Mac is established.

However, when I try to play any video, the spinner appears and keeps on spinning but a video never plays.

This seems to be a common issue but so far I have been unable to find a solution.

`Samsung TV UN60F8000`

`Plex for Samsung 2.003`

`Mac OS X 10.10.4`

Answer (score 1):

I *may* have found a solution.

*Preferences* / *Settings* → *Server* → *Network* → *Secure Connections* → Disabled

Comment: turning off secure connections is, at best, just a workaround

Answer (score 1):

Your Samsung TV may not be able to play the format of the video file you have. Your mac is then spinning around trying to transcode it into a different format before streaming that to your tv.  A solution is to re-encode the videos before hand into a format your tv likes. You can do that with ffmpeg.  source: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=transcode+videos+for+plex

Answer (score 0):

Actually my solution was as follows: The external drive had some how changed drive letter and what plex was searching for was N: drive, whereas my movie drive (external USB), was registered as J: , this is strange as it used to work but decided to change by itself or perhaps through another installed program, could be many reasons in fact. After changing the drive letter to N: it started working promptly. You can change this by going to Windows Settings, Drive Management and changing drive letter for the external drive.

Comment: Mac OS doesn't have drive letters ;) I doubt your solution would be applicable here (Ask Different is for Apple's OSs - MacOS, iOS, etc).